# Open URL in new window in Firefox and not in tab

Tags: firefox

How do I make Firefox open a URL in a new Window and not in a tab by default?

In Thunderbird, when I click, I get the URL opened in a tab. I would like to have a new window spawned. The specific version I am on is Firefox 94.0.

Answer (score 1):

you can make this in firefox in `about:preferences`

[image: about:preferences]

make sure option open links in tabs instead of new windows is not ticked.

Answer (score -1):

It is available in the options:

Firefox -> hamburger menu (upper right) -> Settings -> General -> Tabs -> "Open links in tabs instead of new window" -> Disabled.